# Error installing php artisan swagger:generate Ubuntu

Tags: laravel-artisan

When installing, showing the following error:

```
Unexpected @OA\JsonContent() in @OA\MediaType(mediaType="multipart/form-da
  ta") in /home/vivugroup.tk/api.vivugroup.tk/app/Http/Controllers/V1/Common/CommonSwaggerController.php on line 62
```

Please guide how to fix it.

Comment: did you get any solution